# jQuery click event only firing once in Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, click

JQUERY CODE

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#about').css("opacity","0");
$('#decoy').css("opacity","0");
$('#clickabout').css("opacity","0.2");
$('#clickdecoy').css("opacity","0.2");

function clickhq(){

   $('#clickhq').css("opacity","1");
    $('#clickabout').css("opacity","0.2");
    $('#clickdecoy').css("opacity","0.2");
    $('#hq').animate({opacity:"1"},2000);
    $('#about').animate({opacity:"0"},1000);
    $('#decoy').animate({opacity:"0"},1000);
}

function clickabout(){

    $('#clickhq').css("opacity","0.2");
    $('#clickabout').css("opacity","1");
    $('#clickdecoy').css("opacity","0.2");
    $('#hq').animate({opacity:"0"},1000);
    $('#about').animate({opacity:"1"},2000);
    $('#decoy').animate({opacity:"0"},1000);
}

function clickdecoy(){

    $('#clickhq').css("opacity","0.2");
    $('#clickabout').css("opacity","0.2");
    $('#clickdecoy').css("opacity","1");
    $('#hq').animate({opacity:"0"},1000);
    $('#about').animate({opacity:"0"},1000);
    $('#decoy').animate({opacity:"1"},2000);

}

$("#clickhq").on('click',clickhq);

$("#clickabout").on('click',clickabout);

$("#clickdecoy").on('click',clickdecoy);

});
```

HTML CODE

```
<div id="content">

<div id="activityicons">
<img id="clickhq" src="images/hq.png" width="139" height="139" />
<img id="clickabout" src="images/out.png" width="139" height="139" />
<img id="clickdecoy" src="images/decoy.png" width="139" height="139" />
</div>

<div id="activityiconstext">

<div id="hq">
</div>

<div id="about">
</div>

<div id="decoy">
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Basically, when the user clicks on one of the three images, jquery should fade in / out the relevant content. This works fine in jsfiddle, IE and firefox, but not in chrome and safari.

A live link can be viewed here: http://www.alexkearns.co.uk/35norwich/scouts/index.php

Comment: FWIW try not to build/declare your functions in your $(document).ready function. Those can be pulled out and just in a straight JS file

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that your img can be clicked once at http://www.alexkearns.co.uk/35norwich/scouts/index.php.

But the html and js code you provided responds to the click events within chrome, firefox, and IE.

So, how are we to reproduce the problem?

Comment: What I forgot to mention in the post is that you should be able to click on a different icon even after you've clicked on one for the first time to change between the content. In chrome and safari, once you have clicked on one of the images, you cannot click on any of the other images

Comment: Yes, and the code you provided allowed me to click on multiple icons multiple times within chrome. Since you found a workaround in php, it looks like something else was going on in your script that you didn't realize was affecting your js.

Answer (score 0):

Change the source of jquery url from

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have empty your cache after changing the url?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using a workaround involving PHP and only displaying content if a particular GET variable was set